# Android - Jetpack compose default background color in non Scaffold Composables

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am implementing theming using Jetpack compose. I define my theme like below and everything works fine if I use `Scaffold` as my Composable's parent for each fragment.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalColors provides if (isDarkTheme) {  DarkColorPallet } else {  LightColorPallet }
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors(LocalColors.current),
        shapes = Shapes( medium = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp) ),
        content = content
    )
}
```

But in one fragment I use `Box` as a parent Composable. In this fragment the background is a color that is not defined in my colors implementation. I don't understand where it comes from and how to override it. It's a dark color when Dark mode is enabled and white when it's not. So it must come from some theming mechanism but which one? I also checked the themes.xml files and there was nothing there either.

Comment: Did you define `android:background` in your xml theme?

Comment: I also have this issue. The problem is easily solved when it comes to color of text and things because you can use a `CompositionLocal` to provide a custom `LocalContentColor`, but there is no `LocalBackgroundColor` to customize. This affects the background in our previews where nothing looks right until/unless we had a scaffold or surface as the first composable in the preview. It feels like we shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the LightColorPalette variable you will see this:

```
/* Other default colors to override
background = Color.White,  -> here it says the background color is white in LightColorPalette by default
surface = Color.White,
onPrimary = Color.White,
onSecondary = Color.Black,
onBackground = Color.Black,
onSurface = Color.Black,
*/
```

if you want to change the background color of the box then you should do either one of these :

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red) // you can choose other colors as well
   )
```

But if you want to give a custom color then :

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color(0xFF338E3A)) // you can pass the hex value inside the color function to get a custom color 
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

For Containers like **Box** you can give background color using the **Modifier.background**,

```
Box(
    Modifier
       .background(Color.Red)
        .fillMaxSize()
    ) {}
```